# Scraping text inside both a div and span tag using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to find a specific bit of text from a website. The text is located under a div tag with class = value-highlight, however the same tag also contains a span tag inside it. The text is inside the div tag, but not inside the span tag. I have been able to extract the text contained in the span tag, but cannot find a way to extract the text I am looking for.

The html is set up like so:

```html
<div class="value-highlight"> 
The text I want
   <span class="vals">The text I don't want
</span>
</div>
```

This is the code I have tried

```r
html <- read_html(TESTURL)

val <- html %>% html_nodes('.value-highlight') %>% html_text()
```

It only returns the text I don't want

Answer (score 2):

You can use XPath and `text()` function for this:

```r
library(rvest)
html <- r"(<div class="value-highlight"> 
The text I want
   <span class="vals">The text I don't want
</span>
</div>)"

minimal_html(html) |> 
  html_elements(xpath = "//div[@class='value-highlight']/text()") |> 
  html_text2()
#> [1] "The text I want" ""
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>